# Error when a Angular 8 Library is used as a npm package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-aot, angular-cli-v8

I have built a angular 8 library that compiles perfectly and I can pack it with npm pack command to use it in other project as a npm package. When I use that library in other project I can serve it or build it in JIT mode without a problem. The problem occurs when I do this in AOT mode.

The error that shows the aot compilation of the project is this one:

**ERROR in Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null**

I cannot see anything more than that. After digging more in the problem I found that the problem is inside the node_modules. This is the error path:

**\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js**

***Project Versions:***

- Angular CLI: 8.3.25
- Node: 10.15.3
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 8.2.14

```
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.25
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.3.25
@angular/flex-layout               8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/http                      7.2.16
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.25
```

***Library Versions:***

- Angular CLI: 8.3.25
- Node: 10.15.3
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 8.2.14

```
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.25
@angular/cli                       8.3.25
@angular/http                      7.2.16
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.25
@schematics/angular                8.3.25
@schematics/update                 0.803.25
ng-packagr                         5.7.1
```

The main problem is that I cannot know where the problem or error is located.

Hope you can help me! :)

Comment: I know, but how can I debug that error if any information is thrown?

Comment: @dota2pro I have checked the ng build --aot with --source-map and the error is still the same. If I try the ng serve or ng build it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes and still the same error @dota2pro

Comment: As you see in the question the problem is not the indexOf in my application. It is related to the node_modules/angular/compiler and I think it´s not a good idea to change that part

Comment: But do you think the problem is using indexOf in my library?

Comment: @dota2pro I have wrapped all the indexOf as you said and the error is still the same... :(

Comment: Only thing now that comes to my mind is create a new project with cli from scratch and try copy pasting your code in it, angular 8 has workspace  https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: Yep, I was trying that now. Maybe it works if I have the project and the library in the same workspace.